# Drop down not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem Question -

I have a two drop down in my view. And second drop down rely on the first one. But somehow second one does not get updated

// my firstdrop down

```
  <select ng-controller="myController"
             ng-options="customer.name for customer in customerDetailData"  ng-model="customer"
             ng-change="updateCost(customer)">
                <option value="">Please select customer</option>
    </select>
```

// my second drop down

```
<select ng-controller="myController"
         ng-options="cc.name for cc in customerCostData">
      <option value="">Please select cost</option>
</select>
```

// my controller

```
(function() {
    var myController = function($scope,Service){
        $scope.customerDetailData;
        Service.cust()
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                $scope.customerDetailData = data;
            })
            .error(function(status,error){

            })

        $scope.customerCostData;
        $scope.updateCost=function(customer){
            Service.cost(customer.id)
                .success(function(cost){
                    $scope.customerCostData= cost
                })
                .error(function(status,data){
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(data);
                })
        }
    };
    myController .$inject = ['$scope','Service'];
    angular.module('app').controller('myController ',myController );
}());
```

Is anything i am missing ? the data is coming through fine in the console. Please guide me

Comment: Add ng-model to second dropdown (<select>), it should work

Comment: I don't think so that's the problem.

Comment: My guess is that the `ng-model` value is the same as the temporary variable in your `ng-options`. Try changing it to `selectedCustomer` or something like that.

Comment: @JamesKleeh nope does not work, its the view that not getting update. In the console I can see the oject coming through

Comment: For once try adding a ng-model. It did the trick for me when I faced similar kind of situation

Comment: @RandomUser first thing that I tried mate. Its my $scope.customerCostData not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things to do here:

1. The first and main issue is that you are attaching `ng-controller` to each `select` individually. This means it is actually creating 2 separate controllers, one for each select, and so they are given different scopes. You need to apply the `ng-controller` attribute to a parent element, such as the `form`.
2. The second issue is that angular will not automatically update an element just because the scope variable is used in `ng-options`. You therefore need to give it a `ng-model` so that Angular watches it correctly.

Here is an example of the code with two separate controller instances. Note the 2 alerts:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <form ng-app="myApp">
         <select ng-controller="myController"
             ng-options="customer.name for customer in customerDetailData"  ng-model="customer"
             ng-change="updateCost(customer)">
            <option value="">Please select customer</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-controller="myController"
            ng-options="cc.name for cc in customerCostData" ng-model="customercustomerCostData">
            <option value="">Please select cost</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            var myController = function ($scope) {
                alert('myController created');
                $scope.customerDetailData = [{ id: 1, name: "bob" }, { id: 2, name: "fred" }];

                
                $scope.updateCost = function (customer) {
                    $scope.customerCostData = [{ name: customer.id.toString() }, { name: 'x' }];
                }
            };
            myController.$inject = ['$scope'];
            myApp.controller('myController', myController);
        }());
    </script>
```

Here it is with the single `ng-controller` applied to the `form` and `ng-model="customerCostData"` on the second `select`, so it now works:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
         <select
             ng-options="customer.name for customer in customerDetailData"  ng-model="customer"
             ng-change="updateCost(customer)">
            <option value="">Please select customer</option>
        </select>

        <select
            ng-options="cc.name for cc in customerCostData" ng-model="customercustomerCostData">
            <option value="">Please select cost</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

            var myController = function ($scope) {
                alert('myController created');
                $scope.customerDetailData = [{ id: 1, name: "bob" }, { id: 2, name: "fred" }];

                
                $scope.updateCost = function (customer) {
                    // would be an ajax call
                    $scope.customerCostData = [{ name: customer.id.toString() }, { name: 'x' }];
                }
            };
            myController.$inject = ['$scope'];
            myApp.controller('myController', myController);
        }());
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It solved the problem. A good lesson learned keep angular controller thin and only use ones.

Answer (score 0):

is the cost data the result of an Ajax request? if so, you may need to force a force a $digest cycle to let the UI know the model has been changed. You can achieve this by wrapping the assignment of cost in a $timeout, or $apply.

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.customerCostData = cost;
});
```

or

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.customerCostData = cost;
});
```

Comment: yes it a result of Ajax request. Unfortunately your solution does not work :(

Comment: somehow my $scope.customerCostData is not getting updated any idea? i get my object in console.